# OutOfMemoryError when compiling my android app with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, out-of-memory

I'm trying to build my app via gradle and I'm currently having this issue after running a `./gradlew build`:

```
:myApp:compileDebug


The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Position$LineMapImpl.build(Position.java:139)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Position.makeLineMap(Position.java:63)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocCommentScanner.getLineMap(DocCommentScanner.java:438)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:512)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:550)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parseFiles(JavaCompiler.java:804)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:727)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:353)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:115)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.jdk6.Jdk6JavaCompiler.execute(Jdk6JavaCompiler.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.jdk6.Jdk6JavaCompiler.execute(Jdk6JavaCompiler.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.DelegatingJavaCompiler.execute(DelegatingJavaCompiler.java:29)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.DelegatingJavaCompiler.execute(DelegatingJavaCompiler.java:20)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.execute(IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.execute(IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.java:24)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.Compile.compile(Compile.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:216)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:122)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.call(Unknown Source)
:myApp:compileDebug FAILED
```

Any idea?

Comment: You can also try the --no-daemon gradle arg. If there is a daemon running it won't pick up the changes until it is restarted.

Comment: For those coming across this error in Android Studio, go to Build -> Clean Project and it solved it for me.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In my project there was a `gradle.properties` file with these lines:

```
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

I uncommented the last line, and that worked.

Comment: Actually I changed last line to: 
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Comment: MaxPermSize support was removed in 8.0! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339707/permgen-elimination-in-jdk-8

Comment: Check out this doc on where `gradle.properties` file locates and the loading order: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties

Answer (score 32):

I think I fixed it. I got the solution from [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adt-dev/BY3GEIVGumU/ogYYDaWf-8gJ). i.e:

replacing in gradlew:

```
GRADLE_OPTS="$GRADLE_OPTS \"-Xdock:name=$APP_NAME\" \"-Xdock:icon=$APP_HOME/media/gradle.icns\""
```

by

```
GRADLE_OPTS="$GRADLE_OPTS \"-Xdock:name=$APP_NAME\" \"-Xdock:icon=$APP_HOME/media/gradle.icns\" \"-Xmx1024m\" \"-Xms256m\" \"-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m\""
```

Comment: This solution worked great for me. This java heap space problem was annoying. IT was not a problem for debug build though.

Comment: There is also a DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS variable at the top of the gradlew file where you can put the options. DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="\"-Xmx1024m\" \"-Xms256m\" \"-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m\""

Comment: For windows you have to change gradle.bat instead of gradlew. That also worked for me (giving a Kotlin training and running against this problem.. :-S). Moreover, it modified DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS. Thanks!

Comment: this sounds like a hack, it's much better to use the gradle.properties as mentioned in @dfrankow's answer

Comment: Probably, this was written 9 years ago 

Answer (score 7):

I also faced this problem on regular java project. Our test execution was extensive and used to run out of memory or permgen error.

So there are two soluton
1.  Set the parameters and the run the build

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512M" 
export GRADLE_OPTS="-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
```

Second option simplifies the solution within in gradle file

```
test {
    jvmArgs "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
}
```

I recommend second option as its permanent fix.

Comment: MaxPermSize support was removed in 8.0! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339707/permgen-elimination-in-jdk-8

Comment: Yes, my work was on Java7. Things would have changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
dexOptions {

        incremental true

       //javaMaxHeapSize=1024M for 32bit Java,2048M for 64bit Java

       javaMaxHeapSize "1024M"

       //javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I reproduced the "The system is out of resources" error (but with another stacktrace) by hardcoding a ridiculously large string into a source file.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the JAVA_HOME folder to the 64-bit installation helped me too.
Use 64-bit runner for IDEA after that.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue on my build server, once I changed the JAVA_HOME folder to the 64-bit installation of Java the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Gradle and **Kotlin**, nothing here worked and I spent hours looking for a solution. Here's what worked for me:

Add this anywhere to your `build.gradle`:

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xjsr305=strict', '-XXLanguage:-NewInference']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I had this issue as well with a springboot project. I ended up by running the clean task and the problem was solved.