# Does JVM stores complete bytecode in its memory?

Tags: java, jvm

As mentioned in [answers to my SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119478/permgen-space-of-heap/20120249#20120249), `permgen` space has bytecode of methods.

**What all things java class has?** Its either *fields* or *methods(constructor too)*. And methods are what constitute major part of code.

I am really confused that why almost complete `.class` file(bytecode) is loaded to JVM's memory(if this is true).

Can anybody please clarify?

Comment: but the garbbage collector will deal-located the memory (deletes)..

Comment: @ManetiVinay in permgen space memory is not de-allocated till class loader reference is lost.

Comment: Well it has to load it *somewhere* or it won't be able to run it.  And while methods may constitute a large portion of your *source code*, they are *tiny* compared to the data you operate on if your program does anything interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JVM loads an entire class into memory because it constitutes a single executable unit.  In the native world, entire executables (.exe for example) are loaded, or entire dynamic libraries (.dll, .so, .dynlib) are loaded into memory as a single unit.  Compared to this, Java is actually somewhat more efficient in that only classes that have been directly referenced by another executing class are loaded.

For example:

```
class A {
    public A() {
    }
}

class B {
   public void method1() {
      // do something
   }

   public void method2() {
      A a = new A();
   }
}
```

Even when class B is loaded, and even though class B has a reference to class A, class A will not be loaded by the JVM.  *If* `B.method2()` is called, only at that point does the JVM resolve class A.

Once a class is loaded, the only way to "unload" it is to throw away the ClassLoader that performed the load.  But even so, this provides much more flexibility at runtime than is afforded by many other languages and runtimes.