# JDK 8 Memory Layout and garbage collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-8

From what I [know](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/122), starting with JDK 8 the PermGen will be a past page in java's history. Everything nice and merry... but what will the new Memory Layout look like? Will this affect GC on the new platform?

Comment: Note that "Java Memory Model" has [a *very specific meaning*](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-memory-model/info) which is not really related to what you're asking. Yes, the name is confusingly similar to what you're asking.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[PermGen is replaced with Metaspace](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2013/02/java-8-from-permgen-to-metaspace.html) in Oracle/Sun JDK8, which is very similar. The main difference is that Metaspace can expand at runtime.

Comment: OK...so how much can it grow? is it bound by just the maximum amount of memory a java process can have?

Comment: @user503413 Based on the link I provided: "By default class metadata allocation is limited by the amount of available native memory (capacity will of course depend if you use a 32-bit JVM vs. 64-bit along with OS virtual memory availability)." It can be also limited with `MaxMetaspaceSize` parameter

Answer (score 25):

This is when permGen is there
[image]

After Metaspace is introduced
[image]

Definitely, there is lot of improvement in GC in Java 8.
You can check this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339707/permgen-elimination-in-jdk-8/22509753#22509753)

In Metaspace, multiple mapped virtual memory spaces are allocated for metadata and allocation ( in chunks) is per class loader depending on the type of classloader and its liveness .
Chunks are returned to free chunks list and also virtual memory spaces returned when emptied.

Advantage of GC would be

- During full collection, metadata to metadata pointers are not scanned
- A lot of complex code (particularly for CMS) for metadata scanning was removed.
- Metaspace contains few pointers into the Java heap.
- No compaction costs for metadata
- Reduces root scanning (no scanning of VM dictionary of loaded classes and other internal hashtables).

Comment: Can you please clarify what are the 'VM metadata' exactly?
Also what are so-called 'Internal Hotspot types' and how they have been affected?