# Orbeon running on Weblogic 10.3 on Ubuntu Server 13.10 PermGen space Error

Tags: ubuntu, orbeon, weblogic11g

As the title tells I am running 64bit on Ubuntu Server.

I am getting the following when clicking on form builder link.

```
Error 500--Internal Server Error

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.groupBy(TraversableLike.scala:333)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.groupBy(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.analysis.PartEventHandlerAnalysis$class.registerEventHandlers(PartEventHandlerAnalysis.scala:50)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.analysis.PartAnalysisImpl.registerEventHandlers(PartAnalysisImpl.scala:45)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.analysis.PartAnalysisImpl$$anonfun$analyze$1.apply$mcV$sp(PartAnalysisImpl.scala:227)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.analysis.PartAnalysisImpl$$anonfun$analyze$1.apply(PartAnalysisImpl.scala:184)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.analysis.PartAnalysisImpl$$anonfun$analyze$1.apply(PartAnalysisImpl.scala:184)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.util.Logging$class.withDebug(Logging.scala:50)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.analysis.PartAnalysisImpl.withDebug(PartAnalysisImpl.scala:45)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.analysis.PartAnalysisImpl.analyze(PartAnalysisImpl.scala:184)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsStaticStateImpl.(XFormsStaticStateImpl.scala:54)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsStaticStateImpl$.createFromStaticStateBits(XFormsStaticStateImpl.scala:127)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsStaticStateImpl.createFromStaticStateBits(XFormsStaticStateImpl.scala)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsToSomething.readStaticState(XFormsToSomething.java:255)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsToSomething.access$300(XFormsToSomething.java:46)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsToSomething$3.read(XFormsToSomething.java:150)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsToSomething$3.read(XFormsToSomething.java:138)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readCacheInputAsObject(ProcessorImpl.java:363)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsToSomething.doIt(XFormsToSomething.java:137)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsToSomething.access$000(XFormsToSomething.java:46)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsToSomething$1.readImpl(XFormsToSomething.java:64)
```

In setDomainEnv.sh I have set all 64 bit variables to be Xms2048m or Xmx2048 yet still PermGen space errors. This is a brand new install of Ubuntu and one other app is attached to the WL server which works with no memory issues.

Any help greatly appreciated. Am quite new to Ubuntu/Linux etc

Comment: I added more memory to the virtual machine and this seems to ease the problem a bit. Getting connectivity issues now when one of the apps tries to look up LDAP (so DNS lookup) it then boots all connections (weblogic console/apps, putty, winscp everything!) so god knows what is wrong now!

Answer (score 0):

PermGen is not impacted at all with `-Xmx`. You need to use `-XX:MaxPermSize` for this, for example:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Java 8 BTW [removes PermGen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339707/permgen-elimination-in-jdk-8).