# SonarQube java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, sonarqube, devops

I am getting `OutOfMemoryException` while performing sonar analysis on my project. Jenkins job shows analysis report was generated successfully but during background task in `SonarQube` it is failing with below exception.,

```
2016.08.24 10:55:52 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute comment measures | time=14ms
2016.08.24 10:56:01 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Copy custom measures | time=9075ms
2016.08.24 10:56:02 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute duplication measures | time=150ms
2016.08.24 10:56:34 ERROR [o.s.s.c.c.ComputeEngineContainerImpl] Cleanup of container failed
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
2016.08.24 10:56:34 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to execute task AVa6eX7gdswG1hqK_Vvc
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2016.08.24 10:56:34 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=iServe | id=AVa6eX7gdswG1hqK_Vvc | time=53577ms
```

Comment: Clearly it is running out of memory, you need to provide some sort of information about how much memory the system has and how much sonarqube is using before it crashes.

Comment: Yes, i have increased memory opts for compute engine, Web source and Java as below but nothing helped.
sonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xmx1024m -Xms128m

Answer (score 3):

I use docker-compose and this option works perfectly for me.

```
version: "2"

services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube
    command: -Dsonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xmx4096m
```

You can costumize the memory size.

Answer (score 2):

I know this late, but might help someone :

Try to increase ***MaxPermSize***

I have these configurations under respective **JVM Options** (web/ce/Elastic search) of **sonar.properties** file :-

> sonar.web.javaOpts =-Xmx8512m -Xms512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m /
>   sonar.ce.javaOpts =-Xmx8512m -Xms512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m /
>   sonar.search.javaOpts =-Xmx8512m -Xms512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

For me, it actually worked with '1024m', just because I had multiple modules in my project and just as a hint my server as well need same size for deployments.

Comment: MaxPermSize is ignored in Java 8+ and actually issues a warning, which might break some builds https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339707/permgen-elimination-in-jdk-8

Answer (score 0):

Hi i solved this problem in two ways for two different scenarios where i found this issue

1. Case : when using jenkins :: I was also facing this problem some time ago, my sonar analysis worked fine on command line but it failedon jenkins, you  can replace %SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS% with -Xms256m -Xmx1024m to increase the heap size in sonar-runner bat file.
2. Case : when using command line :: i also got this errorsometimes when i was using cmd line to run sonar analysis , in which cas the solution is to create more number of modules, it somehow works and i dont get java out of mem error.
3. For Linux systems :
   Edit ./sonar-scanner-2.6.1/bin/sonar-runner file and add

```
  SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS="$SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"
  **Note:- SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS is deprecated**.

  if [ -n "$SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS" ] ;
then
  echo WARN: '$SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS' is deprecated. Please use '$SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS' instead.
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: So i need to add this in sonar-runner.properties file right ? not in sonar.properties ?

Comment: Same issue., 2016.08.24 13:06:21 ERROR [o.s.s.c.c.ComputeEngineContainerImpl] Cleanup of container failed
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
2016.08.24 13:06:21 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to execute task AVa679P4xqcL0-osYQgv
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2016.08.24 13:06:21 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=ICALL | id=AVa679P4xqcL0-osYQgv | time=84848ms

Comment: You right click `bin/sonar-runner.bat ` and select edit, in that file you'll find %SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS%, set its value according what you may think should be enough and run the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and added `-Xmx2048m -XX: MaxPermSize = 1024m` in the **JVM Options** and the scanning process went smoothly.

Comment: Where did you add those options? Did you change a config file, environment variables, or did you do it as a command line argument?

Comment: in the JVM arguments while you want to do scanning job process

Comment: MaxPermSize is ignored in Java 8+ and actually issues a warning, which might break some builds https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339707/permgen-elimination-in-jdk-8