# Is it mandatory to have -XX:PermSize in a java process?

Tags: java, weblogic

We have Weblogic process running on JVM and it has `-Xms4G -Xmx4G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90`  ... etc

Java HotSpot VM JDK is: 1.7
We have not included `-XXPermSize` in JAVA arguments

Question:
my question is do we need to include `-XXPermSize` in the memory arguments or it takes from the heap memory ( `Xms` & `Xmx` ) itself?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't set `-XX:PermSize` and `-XX:MaxPermSize` explicitly some default values will be used. According to [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/permgen-and-metaspace)

> Java 7 and earlier starts with something around 12-21 MB of the initial PermGen space

and default maximum is

> - 32-bit client JVM: 64 MB
> - 32-bit server JVM: 64 MB
> - 64-bit JVM: 82 MB

Java 8 and later has [no PermGen space at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22509753/2158271).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I appreciate